# Add functions to google home

Tags: google-home

I'm trying to make a diy IOT light that integrates with my google home, however I have no clue how to go about this. What I prefer is some sort of webhook that gets called everytime I say "set the lights on my desk to 75%"

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into the [Smart Home API for Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/).

This is the API that is available to all IoT device makers - big industry and home developers alike. It provides access to voice commands such as "set the lights".

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding it but how can I use this? I don't really understand what to do. From what I understand this is to connect to other IoT devices, not homemade ones?

Comment: Updated answer - but if you have specific problems with it, please update your question to indicate what the specifics are. The downvotes and votes to close are probably because you haven't really explained your problem or what you've tried so far. Perhaps I'm not understanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: No I think this could be the right thing just I don't know how to use it. I wish there was a simple example that only outputs commands to the console